# What would the physical implementation of the annihilation operator look like?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

If I implement the annihilation operator physically and my system is in the $ |0\rangle$ state, what does it mean to apply this operator on this state? What does it mean for the state to be annihilated?

Comment: That $|0\rangle$ is in the kernel of the annihilation operator? Physically? It gets you out of your Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Schrodinger equation is unitary (meaning it preserves the norm of the wavefunction), and since $|0\rangle$ has unit norm while $0$ has zero norm, the wavefunction will never evolve from $|0\rangle$ to $0$.

The equation $a|0\rangle=0$ is an algebraic statement about the spectrum of the quantum harmonic oscillator (QHO), it doesn't represent a physical process. A physical interpretation of this equation is that there exists a lowest energy state in the spectrum of the QHO.